# Как добавить свой ярлык на панель задач Windows 11?

Tags: windows

В связи с выходом Windows 11 я задался вопроссом:
Как добавить свой ярлык на панель задач (включая ярлык папки)?

Процесс:
По сути панель задач W11 такая же как и в W10, только вырезали возможность добавить свою панель и перетаскивать ярлыки.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаем текстовый документ на рабочем столе.
2. Переименовываем так как нам нужно и меняем расширение на .exe (Например: 'Program Files.exe')
3. Закрепляем его на панели задач. (правой кнопкой мыши и закрепить)
4. Открываем директорию:
   C:\Users*User*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
   (*User* заменить именно на Вашего пользователя!)
5. Видим ярлык 'Program Files' с иконкой блокнота.
6. Открываем его свойства.
7. В графу 'Объект' вводим: C:\Program Files (без кавычек).
8. Графу 'Рабочая папка' очищаем.
9. Меняем иконку на необходимую.
10. Применяем настройки
11. Пуск команда 'Выполнить' вводим 'ie4uinit.exe -show'
    (Очистка кэша иконок Windows,
    для Windows 11 нужно еще перезапустить проводник 'cmd.exe /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe  & start explorer.exe')

(P.S. Был бы очень признателен, если бы кто-то автоматизировал данный процесс, чтобы не делать этого всего ручками.)

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в контекстное меню всех директорий:
Закрепить на панели задач
Открепить от панели задач
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Скачать архив](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/BMttJT497v9TOw), распаковать и следовать инструкциям.
Если есть еще варианты, предлагайте.